# Assumption in isolating ground state of the interacting theory in Peskin & Schroesder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum, approximations, ground-state

In QFT (specifically Peskin & Schroesder), when developing an expression for the ground state of the interacting theory $|\Omega\rangle$, the following expression 
$$e^{-iHt}|0\rangle=e^{-iE_0t}|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|0\rangle+\sum_{n>0}e^{-iE_nt}|n\rangle\langle n|0\rangle $$
is taken and then $t$ is sent to infinity to get rid of the second term under the assumption that $E_n>E_0$. I understand that $e^{-iE_nt}$ dies slowest for $n=0$ when $t\to(1-i\epsilon)\infty$, but is it enough to neglect all other terms?

Comment: I'm afraid the realm of interacting quantum field theory is the realm of approximations and heuristics and unless you're willing to go in rather dark territories that's about the extent of rigor you can hope for!

Comment: You can check Alex Kamenev book, in my opinion this moment is described good enough.

Comment: @Slereah I'm totally OK with approximations when they are justified. I'm not sure how it can be justified it in this case.

Comment: @Artem Alexandrov Is this book available online?

Comment: @v_tal yes but I am not sure that it is free (howeverm it is not a problem)